# Unable to retrieve <a> tag href (starts with "?" instead of http/s) using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

This my first time web crawling and I am trying to web crawl, only the pages (1-...), of the following website:

http://jobs.monster.com/search/?q=data%20science

using python beautifulsoup, but it seems like it's unable to identify the  tag for the pages.
the  tag looks like this:

```
<a href="?q=data-science&amp;page=1" class="page-link">1</a>
```

And part of my code looks like this:

```
import urlparse
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# start with this page
url = "http://jobs.monster.com/search/?q=data%20science"
       #http://jobs.monster.com/search/?q=data%20science&page=2

# stack of urls from nytimes
urls = [url]
#print urls

# visited urls
visited = [url]

while len(urls) > 0:
    try:
        htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
    except:
        print urls[0]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)


    urls.pop(0)

    for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'page-link'}):
        print tag
```

I didn't get any errors, but nothing is printed out either...I am guessing that it's because the href doesn't start with http/s ?

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible that the page you are trying to scrape is dynamically generated by javascript. Neither BeautifulSoup nor urllib executes the javascript, so the page it sees doesn't have the links. Dump the htmltext you are getting into a local file and take a look at what it is actually getting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your site does not contain anchors with the class `page-link` when it is loaded with `urllib`.

However you see it in your browser. This is because JavaScript creates the page links to the next sites. If you use a browser with good developer tools (I use Chrome) you can disable JavaScript execution on sites. If you do this and load the site again you will see the pagination vanish.

But to solve your problem you can extract the job result count and create the URL list based on this value: each site displays 20 job postings. You can divide the result count through 20 and see how many pages you have to crawl. Naturally this works only for searches where the result is under 1000. Over 1000 results you get only "1000+ results" displayed so you cannot really calculate the amount of pages.

However if you look carefully through the source code of the page which is loaded you can locate a JavaScript tag which creates the pagination. This includes the total number of pages which you can use to create your URL list to scrape. Naturally this would include some text parsing but if you invest some time you can find a way how to do it.

And if you have the amount of pages you can create a loop (or generator) and use your commented line for the next url:

```
for p in range(2,page_count+1):
      url = "http://jobs.monster.com/search/?q=data%20science&page="+str(p)
```

or

```
urls = ["http://jobs.monster.com/search/?q=data%20science&page="+str(p) for p in range(2, page_count+1)]
```

The loop starts from 2 because the first site you already have so there is no need to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks GHajba for the detailed explanation!

That's more or less what I ended up doing:

```
try:
    for i in range(2, 100):
        page = urlparse.urljoin(mainUrl, "?q=data%20science&page=" + str(i))
        readPage = urllib.urlopen(page).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(readPage)
except:
    pass
```

Thanks everyone!